# Javascript - Saving image on webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript generator which outputs black, grey and white square. How am I able to right click and save image of the generated image on the webpage?

HTML 
< button onclick="run()">Generate< /button>

```
function run() {

var x = document.getElementById("block");
if (x) {
    x.parentNode.removeChild(x);
}

var rows = 20;
var cols = 20;
var size = 30;

var container = document.createElement("div");
container.id = "block";

for (var i = 0, len = rows * cols; i < len; i++) {
    x = document.createElement("div");
    x.className = "cell";
    x.style.height = size + "px";
    x.style.width = size + "px";
    x.style.backgroundColor = pickColor();
    container.appendChild(x);
}
document.body.appendChild(container);
}
function pickColor(){
var colorArray = ["black", "grey", "white"];
return colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)];
}
window.onload = run;
```

Comment: You are not creating an image here, all you are creating is a DIV with color.

Comment: Might be worth looking into server-side image generation.  You can then serve the image to the client.

Comment: What's the purpose of this image? Do the squares need to be divs, or could you just do all of this in a canvas element?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HTML2Canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) to generate a client-side image of your webpage (or part of it, for example your block element `container`).

```
html2canvas(container, { 
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    var img_data_url = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    document.body.innerHTML += '<img src="' + img_data_url + '"/>';
  }
});
```

The above code will generate an image in an `img` tag of your generated HTML (and append it to your body). The user can then click "Save as" to save the image like he normally would do.